# iPhone custom media player

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to create an iphone app which can play an online radio stream with my own play/pause toggle button and a buffering screen (or buffering state, then I can make the buffering screen). Any suggestions or any sample codes ?

Comment: What have you tried, did search for any solutions your self? Please go and read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I tried my best, if i can do it my own, there is no reason for me to post this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html) like this:

```
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourStraminglink"];
MPMoviePlayerController *streamingPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
[streamingPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[streamingPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[self.view addSubview:[streamingPlayer view]];
[streamingPlayer prepareToPlay];
[streamingPlayer play];
```

and for the audio session to play in background:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try with this code.

```
 - (void)startPlaying
{
   if (streamer)  
   {
           return;
   }

   [self stopPlaying];

   //radio channal url
   streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:cgf.streamURL];
  //NSLog(@"%@",cgf.streamURL);

   // Hard coded URL
   //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.freeproxyserver.ca/index.php?btxmnercdeqt=aHR0cDovLzE5OC41MC4xNTIuNzM6ODAwNC9yaHl0aG0%3D"];
   //streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged:) name:ASStatusChangedNotification
object:streamer];

    //play radio continuously when screen is locked
    UInt32 sessionCategory=kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
    AudioSessionSetActive(true);

}
```